# firebase or MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

We are developing one prestigious product. Can anyone tell me which one is best to use for the backend? firebase or MySQL database/Some OtherDb? This app has features like. Users, profiles management, payments and tracking, and several other things

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Also note we don't do [product comparison](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you can use both equally well.

Note that Firebase is a Google service based on a key-value store, whereas mySQL is a relational database based on tables.

For Firebase only the basic tier is free, whereas mysql is completely free (unless you decide to pay someone, for professional support, perhaps)

Good luck with your prestigious product.